# IOS Swift web view control, hiding the header and footer

Tags: swift, webview, ios10

When using the web view control in IOS 10, how do you hide the header and footer ( the grey boxes)? I am using the UIWebView that I drag to the viewcontrol. The web view has the grey boxes at the time it is placed in the storyboard. I have used the web view with previous versions and didn't see these boxes.

[image]

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [ask].

Comment: is this from an website or from the UI element? which element you use? pls code

Comment: UI element... and if there is an obvious answer I won't mind if you would share ;-)

Comment: I adjusted the top and bottom constraints and was able to hide the dark areas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try setting the web view programmatically:

```
webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height), configuration: null)

let url = URL(string: "http://www.google.com")
let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
webView.load(urlRequest)
self.view = webView
```